# MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django

This error only happens if multiple users have the same title for their posts.

For example, if john has a page with a title 'mypage' this is the error shown if another user has the same title for their page as john.

```
`MultipleObjectsReturned at /john/mypage/update/` get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!
```

but if no one else has it, no error is shown when trying to update the post.

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post 
    form_class = PostForm
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user ##author = current logged in user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True 
        return False 


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post 
    success_url = '/'
 
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True 
        return False
```

Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
        
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug, 'author': self.author})
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('landingpage/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),    
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),

] + static(settings.M
```

EDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: It means that there are *two* `Post`s with as slug `mypage`. Note that you do not filter on the author of your  `Post`, so if two author's have a `mypage`, then this will raise an error.

Comment: Exactly whyere do you store the `author` in your `Post`?

Comment: It's in the post model, i forgot to add it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there are *two* `Post`s with as slug `mypage`. Note that you do not filter on the author of your  `Post`, so if two author's have a `mypage`, then this will raise an error.

You can filter on the author slug with:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post 
    form_class = PostForm

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author__username=self.kwargs['author']
        )
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: That worked! But still getting the same error with PostDeleteView

Comment: @sokoine: you should apply the same "trick" to the `DeleteView` as well.